# Error Running "config = RobertaConfig.from_pretrained( "/Absolute-path-to/BERTweet_base_transformers/config.json""

Tags: nlp, google-colaboratory, bert-language-model, huggingface-transformers, roberta-language-model

I'm trying to run the code 'transformers' version of [this code](https://github.com/VinAIResearch/BERTweet#transformers) to use the new pre-trained BERTweet model and I'm getting an error.

The following lines of code ran successfully in my Google Colab notebook:

```
!pip install fairseq
import fairseq
!pip install fastBPE
import fastBPE

# download the pre-trained BERTweet model zipped file
!wget https://public.vinai.io/BERTweet_base_fairseq.tar.gz

# unzip the pre-trained BERTweet model files
!tar -xzvf BERTweet_base_fairseq.tar.gz

!pip install transformers
import transformers

import torch
import argparse

from transformers import RobertaConfig
from transformers import RobertaModel

from fairseq.data.encoders.fastbpe import fastBPE
from fairseq.data import Dictionary
```

Then I tried to run the following code:

```
# Load model
config = RobertaConfig.from_pretrained(
    "/Absolute-path-to/BERTweet_base_transformers/config.json"
)
BERTweet = RobertaModel.from_pretrained(
    "/Absolute-path-to/BERTweet_base_transformers/model.bin",
    config=config
)
```

...and an error was displayed:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
OSError                                   Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/transformers/configuration_utils.py in get_config_dict(cls, pretrained_model_name_or_path, **kwargs)
    242             if resolved_config_file is None:
--> 243                 raise EnvironmentError
    244             config_dict = cls._dict_from_json_file(resolved_config_file)

OSError: 

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

OSError                                   Traceback (most recent call last)
2 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/transformers/configuration_utils.py in get_config_dict(cls, pretrained_model_name_or_path, **kwargs)
    250                 f"- or '{pretrained_model_name_or_path}' is the correct path to a directory containing a {CONFIG_NAME} file\n\n"
    251             )
--> 252             raise EnvironmentError(msg)
    253 
    254         except json.JSONDecodeError:

OSError: Can't load config for '/Absolute-path-to/BERTweet_base_transformers/config.json'. Make sure that:

- '/Absolute-path-to/BERTweet_base_transformers/config.json' is a correct model identifier listed on 'https://huggingface.co/models'

- or '/Absolute-path-to/BERTweet_base_transformers/config.json' is the correct path to a directory containing a config.json file
```

I'm guessing the issue is that I need to replace '/Absolute-path-to' with something else but if that's the case what should it be replaced with? It's likely a very simple answer and I feel stupid for asking but I need help.

Comment: Have you replaced `/Absolute-path-to/` with the actual path?

Comment: No. That's my question. What is the absolute path? How do I find out what I should replace '/Absolute-path-to/' with?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all you have to download the proper package as described in the github readme:

```
!wget https://public.vinai.io/BERTweet_base_transformers.tar.gz

!tar -xzvf BERTweet_base_transformers.tar.gz
```

After that you can click on the directory icon (left side of your screen) and list the downloaded data:
[image: colab folders]

Right click on BERTweet_base_transformers, choose `copy path` and insert the content from your clipboard to your code:

```py
config = RobertaConfig.from_pretrained(
    "/content/BERTweet_base_transformers/config.json"
)

BERTweet = RobertaModel.from_pretrained(
    "/content/BERTweet_base_transformers/model.bin",
    config=config
)
```

Comment: Ahhh yes it looks like I have downloaded the fairseq files: (
!wget https://public.vinai.io/BERTweet_base_fairseq.tar.gz
!tar -xzvf BERTweet_base_fairseq.tar.gz ) but not the transformers files. Thank you!

Comment: I had a similar problem on Linux machine. It was because wrong permissions on the directory ~/.cache/huggingface where the models should be downloaded